# Array#rotate equivalent in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.rotate         #=> ["b", "c", "d", "a"]
```

`#rotate` is a method of `Array` in Ruby 1.9. I want this functionality in Ruby 1.8.7. What is the ideal code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you [`require 'backports/1.9.2/array/rotate'`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports), you will get `Array#rotate` and `rotate!` in older versions of Ruby.

Either way, you avoid reinventing the wheel, and more importantly you gain the advantage of an implementation that passes RubySpec. It will work for all corner cases and ensure compatibility with Ruby 1.9.

For example, none of the two answers given work for `[]`!

Comment: Backports is a gem, so you need to `gem install backports` as per the installation instructions.

Comment: Thank you, I installed and used the gem fine; Cygwin makes installing things that aren't in the default package frustrating.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve the same with `a.push(a.shift)`. It basically removes the first element (shift) and appends it to the end (push).

Comment: but it changes the original array also..is there a way without changing the original array?

Comment: This would be for `rotate!`, which mutates the array, but it fails for `[]`. It's also not quite compatible with 1.9 as it doesn't accept an argument for how many elements to rotate. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing like coming way late to the party... ;)

Similar to `a.rotate!(n)`:

```
a += a.shift(n)
```

And it works with `a = []`. However, unlike `a.rotate!(n)`, it doesn't do anything if `n` is greater than the length of `a`.

The following preserves the value of `a` and allow `n` greater than `a.length` to work, at the expense of being a little more elaborate:

```
a.last(a.length - (n % a.length)) + a.first(n % a.length)
```

This would obviously be best if `n % a.length` is computed once separately and the whole thing wrapped in a method monkey patched into `Array`.

```
class Array
  def rot(n)
    m = n % self.length
    self.last(self.length - m) + self.first(m)
  end
end
```

Comment: your `rotate` version do change the original array `a`

Comment: @rubyprince ah yes, indeed it does. I think Ruby is a little inconsistent in its method definitions. I think `shift` should leave the Array alone, and they should have a `shift!` to actually modify it directly.

Comment: `shift` method actually returns the shifted element, and it shifts the original array. very useful.

Comment: @rubyprince yes, I'm aware of that. That's what makes it work in the short "rotate" expression, but with the side effect of modifying the original array.

Answer (score 1):

For the rotate! version without the parameter, gnab's is good. If you want the non-destructive one, with an optional parameter:

```
class Array
  def rotate n = 1; self[n..-1]+self[0...n] end
end
```

If n may become larger than the length of the array:

```
class Array
  def rotate n = 1; return self if empty?; n %= length; self[n..-1]+self[0...n] end
end
```

Comment: Both fail for `[]`. See my answer.

Comment: I fixed the second example after Marc-Andre's point, but I agree that `backports` will be better. I did not fix the first one since it's probably of no use.