# Array#rotate produces a NoMethod error

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array#rotate equivalent in ruby 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270098/arrayrotate-equivalent-in-ruby-1-8-7)

According to ruby-doc.org the syntax I'm entering should be working, but it produces a NoMethod error when run in IRB.

```
>> a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
>> a.rotate
NoMethodError: undefined method `rotate' for ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]:Array
    from (irb):14
```

What is the reason for the occurrence of this error?

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using? I tried with 1.9.3 and ruby-head and both worked.

Comment: It's new to Ruby 1.9.

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270098/arrayrotate-equivalent-in-ruby-1-8-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's new to Ruby 1.9. You must be using Ruby 1.8.6 or 1.8.7.

[Here is what you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270098/arrayrotate-equivalent-in-ruby-1-8-7).